# Display only few members of an Excel Pivot Table Filter

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to display only few members of the filter in an excel Pivot Table?

For example:
I have a filter 'Name' which has the following members when I click on the dropdown:
A
B
C
D
E

I would only like to display A to C & exclude D,E,
so that when I click on the dropdown, 
I only see 
A
B
C

Comment: Perhaps you could add an extra column to the source for that pivot that has only values `A` `B` and `C` and leaves any rows with `D` and `E` blank (or `Other` or what-have-you). Then filter on that new column instead.

Comment: Thanks JNevil. To add somemore background, the source is a SQL query and I want to use the same query on two excel sheets, with ABC or one sheet & DE on the other sheet. Would like to keep the data source same. Any other way that you can think of?

Comment: If you are submitting a SQL query to do this, perhaps you could modify the SQL to `SELECT existing_field, CASE WHEN existing_field in ('A','B','C') THEN existing_field ELSE 'Other' END as filter_field FROM yourtable;` ?  Not sure there is any other way to do this.