# How can I apply a display filter on an Excel pivot table in python?

Tags: python, excel, filter, pivot-table

I'm a beginner in python. I'm using win32com.client library. I managed to display a pivot table. I would now like to apply a display filter on specific values. Can anyone help?

I also tried [Display only few members of an Excel Pivot Table Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563522/display-only-few-members-of-an-excel-pivot-table-filter) but the problem is that the pivot table shows items with empty values (sum) in this case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.